# Windows Phone SDK 7.1 Emulator Complete Re-boot Error

Tags: windows-phone-7-emulator

I thank you all for reading this lengthy question. It's really important and I will  appreciate it if you can assist me :)

***The problem -------***

I am have been using the Windows 7.1 SDK for about two months now. The emulator has worked without any problem so far. However, today, it began displaying this error (The saved state (Name of File).dess is corrupt. Please delete the corrupted saved state file and then retry). I had not made any significant changes to my project code, or moved any files. I had just added some Visual State animations for a button.

As it suggested, I went ahead to delete the file. I then started debugging again. However, the emulator now opened and *displayed the message (Windows Phone Emulator is doing a complete OS reboot). This message was displayed for a very long time. I closed the emulator and project. Since then, I have been unable to use the emulator.* I am able to code normally in Visual Studio, but I cannot test my application.

**What I have tried ------**

I read up on this issue and found many others who faced the same emulator issue. Following their suggestions, I have run one repair of the Windows Phone SDK 7.1. I have also tried uninstalling and then re-installing the SDK 7.1 once.

***System Specifications -----***

I am using Visual Studio Express 2010 for Windows Phone (Windows 7 64 bit)

I have downloaded the Windows Phone SDK 7.1 from this link: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=258412

I have read that this issue might be because of some hardware incompatibility. However, I think my machine is compatible with the emulator. Here is some information.

- DirectX Version: DirectX 11
- 8GB RAM
- Driver Model:  WDM 1.1

Additional Information:

I have read that installing the 'January Update' might fix this issue. I tried downloading the update from this link: http://www.microsoft.com/enus/download/details.aspx?id=23854

However, the installer said that the update is not compatible with the product/version of the product I am using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually the Repair function of the WP7.1 SDK is enough to fix all the issues. It runs the generation of the saved state of the emulator again.

Please try to delete files in **%ProgramData%\Microsoft\XDE** folder first (make sure you backup them somewhere else.), then run the emulator. If the emulator runs with a message "*Windows Phone Emulator is doing a complete OS boot*," let it boot. It takes some time though. This way you will know that the emulator actually can run on your computer. This won't generate a new saved state image, but the emulator should at least load.

Next, try installing *WP7.1.1 SDK update* from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29233. This update also installs additional 256MB emulator image besides the original 512MB image. It also generates emulator's saved states in the process, potentially fixing the issue.

If everything fails, then try these instructions to fix the saved state of the emulator:

1. Uninstall *WP7.1 SDK*
2. Manually delete these folders:

   - **%ProgramData%\Microsoft\XDE**
   - **%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\XDE**
3. Install *WP7.1 SDK* again.
4. Install *WP7.1.1 SDK update*: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29233.

**Edit:**
Btw, have you tried to reboot your computer? Once this fixed the issue for me.

Comment: thank you for your swift reply. I will try out the suggestions and get back to you. Thanks!

Comment: I might need more assistance. I deleted the files in the XDE folder, and let the emulator boot. After waiting about an hour and a half, I stopped the emulator and downloaded the WP7.1.1 update.                       Here is the problem. When installation begins, the installer says is "rolling back the components". At this point, my PC crashes!? I have tried this twice and I get the BSOD both times. Really not sure what to do now. :(

Comment: I tried running Visual Studio Express. To debug, I am able to choose to run either the 512mb emulator, or the 256mb emulator. Does this mean the update was successful? Both emulators still have the "complete boot" error though. I'm sorry if I am 'spamming' you!

Comment: My next attempt will be to uninstall the SDK 7.1, delete the folders you mentioned and re-install. On a side note, do you think a full factory reset will solve the issue?

Comment: I have uninstalled and re-installed, after deleting the folders mentioned. However, the problem persists :( I noticed that there no files were created in the \ProgramData\Microsoft\XDE folder during installation. The problem persists even after restoring the deleted files though. I have read some suggestions that enabling virtualisation might fix this issue. Reading up on that now. Please let me know if you know how to proceed, or where else I can get help. Sorry to bother you!

Comment: Try this command in the admin command line:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft XDE\1.0\ImageGen.exe" /g /p {7E6B29E6-AAE1-41dc-9849-049507CBA2B0} /csl 1033
This command attempts to regenerate the saved state. It will probably throw an error. (Write here the error code then.)
But I suppose the problem will be somewhere else. Have you been doing any software installation or HW replacement in the past days?

Comment: On a side note, has the emulator booted to the "Windows Phone" screen with dots running over the screen?

Comment: Unfortunately, no, it has not. I just enabled virtual memory and I'll go ahead to test out your suggestions. Thanks for sticking with me!              I have not done any hardware replacement, and the only software change I have made recently was trying to update to Internet Explorer 10.

Comment: I have run the command. I notice that it starts up the XDE.exe process

Comment: Here is the error (followed by the command line help)                                                     ImageGen: CreateSavedStateImage failed with hr=800705b4Operation failed.

Comment: Command Line Option Help                                                             /g - Targets global saved state cache rather than per user cache.            /i GUID - Installs a saved state image for a device ID identified by the GUID into saved state cache.                                                              /l - Sets the locale ID for the datastore (default 1033)                 /u - Clears the global cache

Comment: Here is some more info you might find helpful. In my previous attempt (when I uninstalled, deleted the XDE folders in the ProgramData and AppData folders, and re-installed), I noticed that there the ProgramData\Microsoft\XDE folder was empty. I understand that installing is supposed to generate the saved state images. However, since this has not happened, does it mean there is an issue with the installer? In any case, thanks alot for helping me out!

Comment: Ok, I think I have figured out why the XDE folder was empty. But first, I'm really sorry if I'm 'spamming' you. I really have to work using the SDK, so this is quite important. I read this forum discussion (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wptools/thread/5b659eea-9a4f-45ce-8418-b9097d586197) and I found someone describing exactly the same issue I am facing. (above comment). From a reply by another user, it seems that while installing/repairing, the installer launches the emulator without the UI, but does not wait for its completion.

Comment: I noticed this after installation as well. The XDE.exe process had been launched. Not knowing what it was doing, I shut it down from the Task Manager. As the user on the forum said, I should wait and let it shut down on its own as it is probably generating the saved state files. As such, this is my plan: Right now, I am going to try installing the SDK 7.1.1 update again. If that does not work, I will uninstall, delete the XDE folders and re-install (but this time, wait for the XDE process to complete). Hope this works!

Comment: The generation tool actually has a timeout of 10 minutes before the execution is halted. If XDE doesn't boot in time, from my own experince ImageGen won't kill it but the image generation does not complete. I also had this very same problem as you have now. Don't know how I solved it. I think some update did it.

I suggest you to try several steps explained here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wptools/thread/5b659eea-9a4f-45ce-8418-b9097d586197. If you have Windows 8 and Hyper-V is enabled, it can prolong the execution time of the emulator; turn Hyper-V off and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I managed to solve this problem.
I reinstalled Windows and downloaded the SDK 7.1 again. The emulator works fine now! 
@Paulos, thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem for a long time. Try this: 
Start up Visual Studio 2010, but before you start debugging, click on the tabs of all the open pages so that all the xaml pages and code behind pages can load.

I noticed it when I opened Visual Studio, but the first open page was a code behind page and not an xaml page, so when I first clicked on the tab of a xaml page, of course, it took some time to load the xaml page into the editor. However, when that and one or more open xaml pages were also loaded, the emulator started without the error message.